# Sharing folders between Windows 7 and Mac

Tags: windows-7, mac, file-sharing

I have a probelem in Windows 7. I just want to share folders on my Mac and I cannot see these folders. I work on a normal PC with Windows 7.

Comment: belongs to poweruser

Answer (score 1):

Thank you I solved it

Goto Start Menu 
Search for: Local
Hit Enter
Select Local Security Policy
Goto Local Policies> Security Options 
Double Click on Network security: LAN Manager Authentication 
Change level to: Send LM # LTLM Responses

Then,

Goto Network security: Minimum session security for NTLM SSP 
De-select Require 128-bit encryption 
Hit OK

I found this somewhere else on the web so can't take the credit, but it works for me and I can see my whole network, macs, windows and shared folders from either, all on windows 7 now.

Comment: I have both of these settings in my corp laptop (IT locks down any such changes, but it is within our policy).  What's next?  I cannot get the two laptops to see each other on the WiFi LAN.